# Function in style.css

Tags: php, wordpress

Hello can someone tell me how can I call a function in style.css.

Something like this:

```
quick-search-input{
    background:#1d1d1d url("<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/icon-search.svg") no-repeat 9px 8px
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to do this in a .css file, you can't.

If the title if your question is a typo and you meant style.php, then you just need to take the PHP block outside of the quotes.  The CSS is treating it as a string literal instead of being parsed as PHP.

```
<?php $my_url = get_template_directory_uri() . "/images/icon-search.svg"; ?>
<style>
  .quick-search-input {
    background: #1d1d1d url(<?php print($my_url); ?>) no-repeat 9px 8px;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

style.css is a plain text file but in your PHP file you can echo something like

```
echo "<style>some css here</style>";
```

In this `echo` command you can use PHP variables and functions.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot dynamically edit a css file. You can insert inline css:

```
<div style="background:#1d1d1d url('<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/icon-search.svg') no-repeat 9px 8px" >
<!--content-->
</div>
```

Comment: @C.Smith You were right. I fixed it now in case you want to see how you could implemented with inline css!